# On Windows, can we put different folders in 1 SVN repository?

Tags: svn

> **Related Question:**
>   [On Windows, can we put different folders in 1 Git or Mercurial (hg) repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027802/3027814)

On Windows, can we put different folders in 1 SVN repository?

Such as putting

```
c:\ror
c:\software projects\ruby
c:\js test
d:\peter_website
```

all in 1 SVN repository called `code` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could. As a svn repository is just a directory structure you could one by one upload them like this. Later you can checkout the whole trunk.

```
trunk/ror
trunk/ruby
trunk/js_test
trunk/peter_website
```

But as I said in the other question about git and hg, you can better keep logical different things separated! And things that are the same, in the same directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you first create the directory structure like Peter Smit wrote, you can check out the individual subdirectories where you want them.

```
C:\>svn co http://yoursvnserver/repos/code/trunk/ror

C:\software projects>svn co http://yoursvnserver/repos/code/trunk/ruby

C:\>svn co http://yoursvnserver/repos/code/trunk/js_test

D:\>svn co http://yoursvnserver/repos/code/trunk/peter_website
```

Then you can delete the working copy where you had http://yoursvnserver/repos/code/trunk checked out if you want.