# On Windows, can we put different folders in 1 Git or Mercurial (hg) repository?

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs

On Windows, can we put different folders in 1 Git or Mercurial (hg) repository?

Such as putting

```
c:\ror
c:\software projects\ruby
c:\js test
d:\peter_website
```

all in 1 Git or Mercurial repository called `code` ?

Comment: this is a related/follow up question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027796/on-windows-can-we-put-different-folders-in-1-svn-repository maybe you could merge this or just edit the question?

Comment: the reason is that if somebody answered the question for SVN, then there tend to be nobody looking at the question any more, so that's why I want two different threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not directly possible. What you could do is making seperate repositories for each dir and then combine them as submodules in another repository.

I would advise to keep a repository about one project only. If these three dirs are for the same project, you might considering using a better directory structure for them.